# Сохранение динамической структуры данных в android приложении

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Ребят,прошу помощи,и прошу не пинать за возможно глупый вопрос,т.к. я в програмировании еще новичек. Несколько дней ломаю голову над такой задачей:
Есть приложение, в котором пользователь может добавлять или удалять задачи, а  так же хранить время потраченное на каждую из них. 
Требования:
Именть возможность добавлять\удалять колонки в таблице,если это SQLite,без потери уже имеющихся в таблице данных.
Впросо собственно,как это реализовать грамотно?

Comment: не понятно, зачем вам удалять колонки у таблицы?

Comment: Советую почитать книгу  Бейли Л. - "Изучаем SQL" - 2012 г. (издательство O'Reilly). Там в очень доступной форме объясняется устройство СУБД, принципы работы с ними, организации данных и тп. в том числе и то, почему нужно удалять записи из БД, а не колонки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `SQLite`. с колонками: id, task, time.

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | task  | time  |
+----+-------+-------+
| 1  | task1 | time1 |
| 2  | task2 | time1 |
| 3  | task3 | time1 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Соответсвенно удалять вам нужно будет только записи из БД. Удалять какие-либо колонки не придется

Comment: точно,вот это я торможу,это же так элементрано,спасибо большое!